# Can Acetone act as a ligand?

Tags: coordination-compounds

I have never seen any [Carbonyl Oxygen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonyl_group) acting as a [ligand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligand). But a naive intution says that since carbonyl oxygen has two lone pairs, it should act as a donor atom, donating one of its lone pairs as shown below:

[image]

In general can aldehydes and ketones act as a monodentate ligand? If no, then what's the reason?

Comment: Why, transition metals are routinely coordinated with acetone, there are hundreds if not thousands of known unique complexes with acetone alone. Even tetrakis(acetone)lithium and hexakis(acetone)sodium are known.

Comment: @andselisk can you provide some references and images? I can't find any. Also can you give an example of transition metal complexes?

Comment: **Li**: https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/structures/Search?Ccdcid=MEHBEG; **Na**: https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/structures/Search?Ccdcid=TOPYUS; **Ca**: https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/structures/Search?Ccdcid=TITQOF; **Fe**: https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/structures/Search?Ccdcid=HOLPUW; **Pt**: https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/structures/Search?Ccdcid=OJECOX.

Comment: Like *everything* can coordinate if there's right Lewis acid present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Examples are known. Coordination can take place through the oxygen atom, as shown in the question, or through the carbonyl pi bond so as to form a metal-carbon-oxygen triangle. See, among others, Huang and Gladysz [1](https://doi.org/10.1021/ed065p298). A couple sample figures from the reference are given below.

[image]

[image]

**Reference**

1. Yo Hsin Huang and J. A. Gladysz (1988). "Aldehyde and ketone ligands in organometallic complexes and catalysis". _J. Chem. Educ. **65**, 4, 298. https://doi.org/10.1021/ed065p298

Comment: Nice downvote there. Would be better if you could give ideas on how to improve this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are numerous examples. Check out some of them:

1. *Chemistry in Acetone Complexes of Metal Dications:  A Remarkable Ethylene Production Pathway*
   Jianhua Wu, Dan Liu, Jian-Ge Zhou, Frank Hagelberg, Sung Soo Park, and Alexandre A. Shvartsburg
   The Journal of Physical Chemistry A **2007** 111 (22), 4748-4758
   DOI: [10.1021/jp068574z](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jp068574z)
2. $\ce{[M(Ac)6^2+][A−]2}$ where M is Mg(II), Ca(II), Sr(II), Mn(II), Fe(II), Co(II), Ni(II), and Zn(II); and $\ce{A−}$ is $\ce{FeCl4−}$ and $\ce{InCl4−}$:  Driessen, W.L. and Groeneveld, W.L. (**1969**), *Complexes with ligands containing the carbonyl group. Part I: Complexes with acetone of some divalent metals containing tetrachloro-ferrate(III) and -indate(III) anions*. Recl. Trav. Chim. Pays-Bas, 88: 977-988.DOI: [10.1002/recl.19690880811](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/recl.19690880811)
3. Troepol'skaya, T.V., Sitdikov, R.A., Titova, Z.S. et al. Synthesis and structure of complexes of acetone acylhydrazones with some transition metals. Russ Chem Bull 29, 903–907 (**1980**). DOI: [10.1007/BF00958804](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00958804)
4. $\ce{[Fe(C19H25N5)(C3H6O)(H2O)2](BF4)2·2C3H6O}$: Kilner, C. A. & Halcrow, M. A. (2006). *An unusual example of a linearly coordinated acetone ligand in a six-coordinate iron(II) complex*. Acta Cryst. C62, m437–m439. ([Link](https://journals.iucr.org/c/issues/2006/09/00/gg3033/))